# How to get a segment button without using its ID in sencha touch?

Tags: html, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.2

```
Code:

     items: [{
            xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
            disabled: true,
            //id:'segmentWidget',
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'text1',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'text2',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'text2',
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]

        }]
```

Ext.getCmp('segmentWidget').setPressedButtons(0);

How can i do this without using ID

Thanks

Comment: I guess you could improve this question by changing it to be more general, this is not really about `segmentedbutton` only but could be about selecting components by properties other than `id`s

Comment: Could you give some feedback on my answer? Did you find it relevant/helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `id` to select components in Sencha (and it is a good idea to do that when possible to keep things reusable and avoiding polluting the global ids space) you have several options.

(**bold** part is taken from Sencha docs, the rest is mine)

1. `Ext.Container.getComponent()` method: **Examines this container's items property and gets a direct child component of this container**. Basically you pass in a string which should match the `id` or `itemId`property of one of the `items` in that container.
2. `Ext.Container.query()` method: **Retrieves all descendant components which match the passed selector. Executes an Ext.ComponentQuery.query using this container as its root.** This returns an array of `Ext.Component`. Take a look at `Ext.ComponentQuery.query`docs to understand which queries you can do. In short, you can simply select by `xtype`, in your case you can do: `fatherComponent.query('segmentedbutton')[0]`, or by another property, for example: `fatherComponent.query('[text=text1]')[0]`
3. `Ext.Component.up()` method: **Walks up the ownerCt axis looking for an ancestor Container which matches the passed simple selector**.